# Setting an upstreamproject in Jenkins using groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I would like to copy a FreeStyleProject to a new job and then set a new upstreamproject to this new job using groovy.
I can't find any method on [Class FreeStyleProject](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/FreeStyleProject.html) that let me do that:
set a new upstreamproject. Is there some other method or trick that can accomplish this?

```
def x = "testproj"
def hi=hi.getItem(x)
hi.copy(x, "Copy"+x); 
def newjob=hi.getItem("Copy"+x)
//newjob.setUpstreamProject("bar") //<<--?
  def di = newjob.getUpstreamProjects()

     for ( y in di ) {

      println(y.name)
}
```

**Update:**
For clarification:

Job A ====> Job B (A is upstream)

I want to copy Both jobs so i get i

Job A' and Job B' and then set A' or B' so I get
A' =====> Job B' (A' is upstream)

I think I need to remove a build trigger and create a new build trigger (that is what creates the upstream/downstream concept it seems)

Comment: An 'Upstream project' is a job that calls your current job - are you sure you want to put yourself in that kind of a loop? What are you really trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a sample of Two FreeStyle projects and one downstream, this snip will found the TestTop and set them to the existing TopTest2.
The concept is to get the buildtriggers with the help of **getPublishersList** on a project and then
get the    hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger.class  of these.

For each of these do a
publishlist.**remove**(aa)
publishlist.**add**( new hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger("TestTop2", false))

```
def hudsonInstance = hudson.model.Hudson.instance 
hudsonInstance.getItems(hudson.model.Project).each {project ->

  if (project.displayName== "TestTop"){
    println(project.displayName)
    def di = project.getUpstreamProjects()
    def triggers=project.getBuildTriggerUpstreamProjects()
    for (z in triggers){
      println("triggers " + z.getDisplayName())

      def pubList = z.getPublishersList()
      for(w in pubList){

        println(w)

        def buildTrigger = w.grep(hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger.class) 

        println("BT " + buildTrigger)
        for(aa in buildTrigger){
          println("aa " + aa.getChildProjectsValue())
          def newtop =  hudsonInstance.getItem("TestTop2")
          pubList.remove(aa)
          pubList.add( new hudson.tasks.BuildTrigger("TestTop2", false)) 
        }               
      }
    }   
  }
}
hudsonInstance.rebuildDependencyGraph()
```